# Problems compiling Android app in release mode with proguard enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to compile my Android app with proguard, but i get the following errors and do not know how to fix them. Anyone has some idea? In debug mode everything compiles fine...

```
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.HostNameResolver]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [org.apache.http.params.HttpParams]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate$DName]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslError]
Note: duplicate definition of library class [android.net.http.SslCertificate]
    Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'title' dynamically
          Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$id { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.internal.VideoUploader$UploadContext { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.model.GameRequestContent { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.facebook.share.model.GameRequestContent$Builder { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.games.internal.player.PlayerColumnNames { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode$ContactInfo { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode$UrlBookmark { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.google.api.client.util.PemReader$Section { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.android.app.R$attr { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.android.app.R$id { int title; }'
          Maybe this is program field 'com.android.app.adapter.InAppListItem { java.lang.String title; }'
          Maybe this is library field 'android.R$attr { int title; }'
          Maybe this is library field 'android.R$id { int title; }'
          Maybe this is library field 'android.app.Notification$Action { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
          Maybe this is library field 'android.preference.PreferenceActivity$Header { java.lang.CharSequence title; }'
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest depends on program class com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest depends on program class com.google.api.client.http.HttpExecuteInterceptor
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest depends on program class com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest depends on program class com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest depends on program class com.google.api.client.util.GenericData
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse depends on program class com.google.api.client.util.GenericData
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Header
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebToken$Payload
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken$Payload depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebToken$Payload
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken$Payload depends on program class com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdToken$Payload depends on program class com.google.api.client.util.GenericData
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenVerifier depends on program class com.google.api.client.util.Clock
        Warning:library class com.google.api.client.auth.openidconnect.IdTokenVerifier$Builder depends on program class com.google.api.client.util.Clock
            Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.apache.http.**' to keep library class 'org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor'
            Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.apache.http.**' to keep library class 'org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestInterceptorList'
            Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.apache.http.**' to keep library class 'org.apache.http.protocol.HttpResponseInterceptorList'
            Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.apache.http.**' to keep library class 'org.apache.http.protocol.SyncBasicHttpContext'
            Note: the configuration explicitly specifies 'org.apache.http.**' to keep library class 'org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils'
            Note: there were 2 references to unknown classes.
                  You should check your configuration for typos.
                  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
            Note: there were 112 library classes explicitly being kept.
                  You don't need to keep library classes; they are already left unchanged.
                  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#libraryclass)
            Note: there were 16 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
                  You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
                  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
            Note: there were 4 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
                  You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
                  (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
                  (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
            Warning:there were 146 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
                     You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
                     be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
                     (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
            Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
            :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
            Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
            > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

My Gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 240
        versionName "2.4.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            proguardFile 'proguard-app.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/AudienceNetwork.jar')
}
```

and here ist my proguard file proguard-app.txt:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature

-keep class com.google.api.client.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.api.client.** {
    *;
 }


-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.gms.** {
    *;
 }
-keep class com.google.gson.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.gson.** {
    *;
 }


-keep class com.google.ads.**
-keepclassmembers class com.google.ads.** {
    *;
 }

-keep class bolts.**
-keepclassmembers class bolts.** {
    *;
 }

-keep class com.google.api.client.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.*
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.*

-libraryjars libs
#-injars libs/AudienceNetwork.jar
#-injars libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
#-injars libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar
#-injars libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar


 # The official support library.
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v4.** {
    *;
 }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.support.v7.** {
    *;
 }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

# Library JARs.
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.facebook.** {
    *;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you applying `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin?

Comment: because google analytics needs this. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Comment: Thanks for the link, asked out of curiosity :)

Comment: May be this http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency and this https://github.com/uservoice/uservoice-android-sdk/issues/147 can help you.

Comment: not really, beacuse it does not explain which packages or modules to exclude

Comment: Try replacing 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' with 
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0' to include only analytics related classes

Comment: I removed 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' and added        

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'

same errors...

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines to your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontnote android.support.v4.**
```

Comment: This helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
```

fixed the problem.